# Center n-divs in row (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have a Bootstrap row containing a variable amount of divs and they need to be centered relative to their parent row. The html is set like this so far:

```
<div class="row proj-container">

    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>

</div>
```

With javascript I clone and append inside .proj-container a variable number of .proj. It works fine and if the .proj are more than 3 they wrap correctly onto other lines thanks to grid disposition. 
What I am not being able to achieve is the centering of this sets of divs inside of their parent.

- assigning ".text-center" to parent doesn't work
- text-align on parent and inline-block on children doesn't work
- making parent flex and justify:space-around achieves centering the children but overrides the grid system (col-md-4) and they won't wrap if more than three or on smaller devices...

Any idea on how to style this in order to achieve centering AND wrapping of the divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more solution. Look at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srLk8yaz/).

```css
.proj {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  float: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row proj-container text-center">
    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="proj col-md-4 col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you nailed it, thank you! I It works even without the more external div with "container-fluid", and also "text-center" on "proj-container" seems to be superfluous. Looks like inline-block and no floating on the very elements to be centered has made the difference. Could you comment on why? Also it would be perfect if the divs that wrap on the last line would stick to the left (if less than 2). I don't know if that's possible but If you have a solution even for that feel free to share. Thank you again!

Comment: I think that `text-center` affects on non-floating inline-block elements. `float: none` doesn't push element to any border (against floating left or right), so non-floating inline element can be aligned within its parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following which should center the grid columns

```
.project-container {
   text-align: center; /* set all inline elements to be centered */
}

.project-container .proj {
  display: inline-block; /* set the columns to inline blocks so they are centered */
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I specified in the question this solution doesn't work. I don't know why the divs don't behave as inline elements even if so displayed. Maybe it's  because they contain a bunch of other elements themselves, but I'm not so sure...

Comment: It's not working because the columns are floated by default (something I forgot to consider).  If you add `float: none;` to `.proj`, it should work.